# Swashbuckle - Same endpoint generating multiple operationIds

Tags: c#, .net, swashbuckle, webapi

In a .NET 4.8  WebApi application, I have a simple controller like

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : WebApiBaseController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RequestPasswordReset([FromUri]string email)
    {
        await RequestPasswordReset(email);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When I generate an api spec with swashbuckle, it creates multiple operations for this.

```
 "/api/Account/RequestPasswordReset": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [ "Account" ],
    "operationId": "Account_RequestPasswordReset",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [ "application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml" ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "query",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "schema": { "type": "object" }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

but then lower down in my spec

```
 "/api/Account": {    
  "post": {
    "tags": [ "Account" ],
    "operationId": "Account_RequestPasswordReset",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [ "application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml" ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "query",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "schema": { "type": "object" }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

How can I make it not generate 2 operations for the same endpoint?

Comment: Which route do you want to keep?

Comment: I only use the fully qualified routes in my app, so in this case the top one.